# How do i read from excel into python at runtime?

Tags: python, excel

Here is a sample code where i am trying to print the number of rows in the excel file each time a new row is inserted.The code does not work ,because i believe it's not interacting with the excel file at run time.

```
import xlrd
loc = r'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\sample2.xlsx'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
k = sheet.nrows
while(True):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    k1 = sheet.nrows
    if(k1 > k):
        print(k1)
        k=k1
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the code is not working?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Until a user (or some automation) saves the sheet - then Excel keeps it in memory so there's no new data in the *file* itself to see until then. It's also unclear what "adding a row" means here... is it just adding a non-blank value to a cell somewhere increasing the size of the sheet etc...?

Comment: you need to read excel again and again after some duration of time by some scheduler like windows task scheduler or cron job in linux. And compare the max_rows of previous read excel to newest read.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand how the library `xlrd` works. It provides you with an interface to Excel *files*, not to an Excel session of an Excel instance somebody is working on in parallel. Everything you do in Excel is not written to the according file until you save the workbook. Hence, this is the moment when your code reads updated cells, not already when cells are changed.